# Why are some Blender UI elements blue?

Tags: interface

In some tutorials I see that sliders, textboxes etc. in the Blender look blue like this one:

[image: screenshot of Blender screen]

In my version of program these elements of UI are grey. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are called themes and they can alter the look and visual appearance of Blender UI.

You can change them from *Blender User Preferences > Themes* and choose from the pulldown menu on the top left.

You can also create your own, modify or customize existing ones or simply download third party created from the internet from places like [BlendSwap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/categories/blender-themes) or search in forums like [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?48-Released-Scripts-and-Themes)