# How can I reset this?

Tags: interface

[image: I did this]

Disclaimer: When I'm referring to "it" I mean the Dark interface!!

I saw that Youtuber that had his Blender looking different. He then told me how he did that (It was something that comes with Blender).

I then activated it, but now i want to disable it. I already tried to reinstall Blender and even delete the Blender foundation folder but nothing worked...
Can you please help me?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52030/why-are-some-blender-ui-elements-blue/52031#52031

Comment: The dark theme is now the default, so resetting will not change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the theme from dark to light in the preferences. Open *Edit > Preferences* then go to Themes and select *Light* from the dropdown. The dark theme is the default in Blender 2.8.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok so i just noticed that you have the same kind of Interface/Theme mode(?)!
I just want to go back to the original interface and keybinds where you have to Right-click to select etc.

Comment: @SlenLen The interface changed from Blender 2.79, Blender 2.8 as a different UI. You can download the old version here https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

Comment: @SlenLen the old keymap can be used. You have to go to the keymap in the preferences and select *Blender 27X* from the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you so much!