# How to change the interface color?

Tags: interface

I was wondering if it is possible to change Blender's interface color?  The dark version is the default  Are there setting that would allow you to change to something lighter?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52030